# Is it possible to adjust the snap feature?

Tags: 11.04, unity, compiz

Is it possible to adjust the snap feature in 11.04? I want something like 2/3 1/3 instead of 1/2 1/2 of the screen.

Answer (score 4):

This feature is controlled by the `Grid` plugin of Compiz. I have seen no way to adjust the size of windows when the snap feature resizes your windows though.

You can use [CompizConfig Settings Manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: Install ccsm] (also known as `ccsm`) to alter its settings.

Comment: I guess it's not possible to adjust those resize actions or to create your own?

Answer (score 3):

Once you've snapped a window, you can resize it using the `Grid` plugin's keybindings. 
The defaults (taken from [CompizConfig Settings Manager](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ccsm) [image: Install ccsm]) are:

[image: Default Grid plugin keybindings]

For example: if you've snapped a window to the left half of the screen, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>

to resize it to 1/3 of your screen's width. You can repeat the keystroke to resize it to 1/4, 3/4, 2/3 and 1/2 of your screen's width.